# Polynomials in $y=e^x$ dense in C[1,e]

Tags: polynomials, weierstrass-approximation

I try to understand a proof of Theorem that I found in Tran van Thuong article. \ Theorem: For each integer $N\ge1$, the set of functions:
{$e^{nx} : n \ge N$} has a linear span dense in $C[0,1]$.
Proof: Put $y=e^x$. By Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, polynomials in y are dense in $C[1,e]$. Moreover given any $f ∈ C[1,e]$, and any $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite sum:
$A_Ny^N + A_{N+1}y^{N+1} + \cdots + A_{N+L}y^{N+L} = Q(y) $,
such that $|f(y)-Q(y)|<\epsilon$. \
My question is: Why polynomials in y are dense in $C[1,e]$ ? And why we consider $f ∈ C[1,e]$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem

Comment: If $f \in C[1,e]$ then $f \circ \log \in C[0,1]$.